# celery 5.3.6 unable to autodiscover task

Tags: docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose, redis, django-celery

I'm running a blog web app inside a docker container, I'm trying to use celery and redis for asynchronous sending of welcome emails to newly registered user.

When I run my docker compose up, everything is setup successfully, the celery, redis broker is running as expected, I can share the docker-compose and Dockerfile below if needed.

The issue is, I'm getting a KeyError when trying to execute the tasks in my tasks.py.

This is the error I'm getting below:

```
celery_1  | [2024-01-22 09:37:50,439: INFO/MainProcess] Events of group {task} e
nabled by remote.
app_1     | [22/Jan/2024 09:39:02] "GET /api/user/create/ HTTP/1.1" 405 8444
celery_1  | [2024-01-22 09:39:16,512: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered t
ask of type 'core.tasks.send_verification_email'.
celery_1  | The message has been ignored and discarded.
celery_1  |
celery_1  | Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
celery_1  | Or maybe you're using relative imports?
celery_1  |
celery_1  | Please see
celery_1  | https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
celery_1  | for more information.
celery_1  |
celery_1  | The full contents of the message body was:
celery_1  | b'[["brain00001@proton.me"], {}, {"callbacks": null, "errbacks": nul
l, "chain": null, "chord": null}]' (99b)
celery_1  |
celery_1  | The full contents of the message headers:
celery_1  | {'lang': 'py', 'task': 'core.tasks.send_verification_email', 'id': '
a9e2b679-a94d-4007-851a-30f0f14764f1', 'shadow': None, 'eta': None, 'expires': N
one, 'group': None, 'group_index': None, 'retries': 0, 'timelimit': [None, None]
, 'root_id': 'a9e2b679-a94d-4007-851a-30f0f14764f1', 'parent_id': None, 'argsrep
r': "('brain00001@proton.me',)", 'kwargsrepr': '{}', 'origin': 'gen10@app', 'ign
ore_result': False, 'replaced_task_nesting': 0, 'stamped_headers': None, 'stamps
': {}}
celery_1  |
celery_1  | The delivery info for this task is:
celery_1  | {'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'celery'}
celery_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
celery_1  |   File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consu
mer.py", line 658, in on_task_received
celery_1  |     strategy = strategies[type_]
celery_1  | KeyError: 'core.tasks.send_verification_email'
app_1     | [22/Jan/2024 09:39:16] "POST /api/user/create/ HTTP/1.1" 201 8643
```

Even when I check for registered task, it shows no task found.

Here's how my celery is configured:

My celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os
import logging

from celery import Celery

logger = logging.getLogger("Celery")

# Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')

# Create a Celery instance and configure it using the settings from Django.
app = Celery('app', include=['core.tasks'])

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Auto-discover tasks in all installed apps
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

init.py:

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

My settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core',
    'user',
    'rest_framework',
    'drf_spectacular',
]
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://redis:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
```

My tasks.py:

```
from celery import shared_task
from django.core.mail import send_mail
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@shared_task
def send_verification_email(user_email):
    try:
        subject = 'Verify your email'
        message = f'Welcome to the test blog application'
        from_email = 'foliocoins@gmail.com'
        recipient_list = [user_email]
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently=False)
        logger.info(f"Verification email sent to {user_email}")
    except Exception as e:
        # Log the exception
        logger.error(f"Failed to send verification email to {user_email}: {e}")
```

The tasks is to be executed in the views.py:

```
"""
Views for the user API.
"""
from core.tasks import send_verification_email
from rest_framework import generics, views
from user.serializers import (
    UserSerializer,

    )


class CreateUserView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """Create a new user in the system."""
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user = serializer.save()
        send_verification_email.delay(user.email)
```

This is how my project struture looks like:

```
BLOG-APP-API/
│
├── app/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── celery.py
│   └── # other py files related to the main app
│
├── core/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── tasks.py
│   └── # other py files related to the core functionality
│
├── user/
│   └── views.py
│   └── # other py files related to the user functionality
│
├── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
└── # other project-level files or directories
```

I need assistance please, is there anything I'm not doing right.

I've used this one pure django project I built and it worked,I don't know why it has refused to work with this one.
Anyone who had had similar experience should please give his/her ideas, Thanks.